# undefined method `users' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create an application having domains and users, there are 3 types of users, super admin,domain admins and domain users.All the users(3 types) are in the users table and domains in domain table. At present there are domains and super admin. A super admin can login and create domains and domain users. The domains users should be related to a particular domain(i have a "domain_id" column in my 'users' table).Now when i am trying to create a user under a domain(after selecting a domain), i am getting this error "undefined method `users' for nil:NilClass".

My user controller.

```
def new
    @domain = Domain.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.new
    @title = "Sign up"
end

def create
    @user = @domain.users.build(params[:user])
    if @user.save
       flash[:success] = "Welcome to My Space!"
       redirect_to @user
    else
       @title = "Sign up"
       render 'new'
    end
end
```

My user model is having.
    belongs_to :domain
    validates :domain_id, :presence => true

and domain model is having.
    has_many :users

My new.html.erb form

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field(:first_name, :size => 20) %>

  <%= f.label :last_name %>
  <%= f.text_field(:last_name, :size => 20) %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field(:email, :size => 20) %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field(:password, :size => 20) %>  

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Verify Password" %>
  <%= f.password_field(:password_confirmation, :size => 20) %>

  <%= f.submit "Create" %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: If my answer does not work, you have to add a hidden field with the id of the domain to your form, or use nested resources. Please add your form code to the question, so we can give suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `@domain = Domain.find(params[:id])` in the `new` method does what it should do:

```
def new
  @domain = Domain.find(params[:id])
  @user = @domain.users.build
  @title = "Sign up"
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to My Space!"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    @title = "Sign up"
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

And your view should look like this:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :domain_id %>

  <%= f.label :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field(:first_name, :size => 20) %>

  <%= f.label :last_name %>
  <%= f.text_field(:last_name, :size => 20) %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field(:email, :size => 20) %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field(:password, :size => 20) %>  

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Verify Password" %>
  <%= f.password_field(:password_confirmation, :size => 20) %>

  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

Because of the hidden `domain_id` field in your form, the user will be assigned to the correct domain.